# Is there a way an Azure customer tenanat to send his domain name as domain_hint to a B2C app

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Currently, we have set up a B2C tenant that supports Local Accounts and SSO with OpenID. The purpose of the tenant is to support our customers. At the moment, the users are presented with the option to sign in with Local Accounts or to click one common button for using their Entra work accounts. Unfortunately, not all of our customers want to use OpenID or allow the use of all of the scopes we require. This all leads to adding more buttons for every specific case for every tenant ( like using SAML for every customer or different OpenID with different sets of scopes). I want to avoid this!

I've read about Home Realm Discovery where the users are presented with a sign-in page to type only their email and based on that to redirect them to the correct Idp. This is one solution, but it still requires users to enter something and I really want to do it with more smoother user experience.

So I was thinking is there a way that the customer Azure Entra tenant can send me the domain_hint, when the user clicks on my App URL, which I can later use to filter the user and redirect him to the correct Idp without prompting with the first sign-in page to collect the email address.

So in short, I want the customer tenant to send his domain name as domain_hint when it hits my App URL sign-in page, if it's possible at all.

Note: All my users use the same URL pointing to the same Custom policy in the B2C.

Thank you,

Georgi